# Unicode not printing

Tags: c++, winapi, unicode

I have the following C++ code

```
char* locale = setlocale(LC_ALL, "German"); // Get the CRT's current locale.
std::locale lollocale(locale);
setlocale(LC_ALL, locale); // Restore the CRT.
wcout.imbue(lollocale); // Now set the std::wcout to have the locale that we got from the CRT.

COORD cur = { 0, 0 };
SetConsoleCursorPosition(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), cur);
wcout << L"Enemy " << this->enemyStrengthLeft << L"/" << this->enemyStrength << endl;
wcout << L"◄";
for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
  if (i % 2 == 0)
    wcout << L"■";
  else
    wcout << L" ";
}
wcout << L"►" << endl;
```

When I execute it, the unicode characters are not in the cmd windows, how can I fix it?

**EDIT**

I use Lucida Console as font.

**EDIT 2**

If it helps, I am running Visual Studio 2013 Express for Desktop under Windows 7 Enterprise SP1 64bit

Comment: Does your console window use TrueType fonts?

Comment: Oh right, I gonna put in the font.

Comment: That looks like Windows, in which case, it expects a `_setmode(_fileno(stdout), _O_WTEXT); ` before you can send wide strings to the standard output.

Comment: In what way are the characters not showing? Are they left out, replaced, or does the entire output stream 'stop' after the first unicode character?

Comment: @Cubbi Yeah it is Windows, but which headerfiles to I need for your "trick"?

Comment: @MicroVirus they are just not showing.

Comment: @Knerd see [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tw4k6df8.aspx)

Comment: @Cubbi when I add your code I get an `AssertionFailure` :/

Comment: Consider using `boost::nowide`? It makes some things a little less awful under Windows.

Comment: @Hook honestly I would like to stay with the Windows API, but if there is no other solution I might take a look :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Windows doesn't support Unicode through the standard library very well. Printing arbitrary Unicode to the console via the standard library can be done but it's not very convenient and all the methods I know of have unpleasant side effects.

Just use the Windows API:

```
std::wstring s = L"◄ ■ ►";
WriteConsoleW(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), s.c_str(), s.size(), nullptr, nullptr);
```

---

On a side note, your code to get the locale and restore it isn't doing what you think, and there's a better way.

```
char* locale = setlocale(LC_ALL, "German"); // Get the CRT's current locale.
std::locale lollocale(locale);
setlocale(LC_ALL, locale); // Restore the CRT.
```

`setlocale` returns the locale name in effect *after* the function runs. So you're always going to get the name of a German locale, and the global locale will not get restored to its original value. If you really want to get the currently set locale then you can do so by passing `nullptr` instead of a locale name:

```
char const *locale = std::setlocale(LC_ALL, nullptr);
```

This gets the current locale without changing it.

However you should know that unless the locale is changed at some point then it will be the "C" locale. C and C++ programs always start in this locale. The "C" locale does not necessarily let you use characters outside the basic source character set (which does not even include all of ASCII, let alone characters like 'ä', 'ö', 'ü', 'ß', '◄', '■', and '►'.

If you want to get the locale that the user's machine is configured to use then you can use an empty string as the name. You can also imbue a stream with this locale without bothering with the global locale.

```
cout.imbue(std::locale("")); // just imbue a stream

char const *locale = std::setlocale(LC_ALL, ""); // set global locale to user's preferred locale, and get the name of that locale.
```

Comment: Works, but I am a bit curios why this works but my solution not. My solution works just perfekt for german ä, ö, ü and ß...

Comment: Because those characters are members of the character set that goes with your locale and their representation happens to be the same in that encoding as in your current console output code page. (The locale encoding is cp1252 and the console code page is cp850.)

Comment: Thank you a lot :) I used your solution :)

Comment: See http://blog.kalmbachnet.de/?postid=98  YOu need to enable unicode support in the CRT: `_setmode(_fileno(stdout), _O_U16TEXT);`

Comment: @JochenKalmbach Yeah, that's one of the alternatives. The downside is that you have to eradicate all char based output because `printf`, `cout`, etc. will crash with that mode enabled.

Comment: @JochenKalmbach Here's VS2012: http://imgur.com/euoKAEc. Maybe this has been fixed in VS2013.